# Drush on Cygwin setup

Tags: cygwin, drush

I followed the instructions [here](https://drupal.org/node/1432756) to install pear and download drush in usr/local/src folder and create the symlink in usr/bin/drush

At the end of the instructions is says you can test by running **drush**. I get this output:

> -bash: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/drush: No such file or directory

Not the bash root of xampp/php. Does that need to be changed?

So, then I tried running **/usr/bin/drush** and got this output:

> Unable to untar C:\cygwin\usr\local\src\drush\lib\dru6B61.tmp.
>   [error]

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I reinstalled the cygwin packages above in the tutorial you mentioned above(I had them already from other installs, I thought). I think it may have been the 'bsdtar' package.
Good luck!

Comment: Yep, bsdtar fixed it for me.